# Render view as JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a page where I render a list of `<divs>`. The view can be accessed from /mylist?username=xxxxx.

Now, I would like each member to embedded this view into their own site.

Ideally, I would like the members to simply copy and paste a snippet of javascript with the source pointed over to me:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/mylist?username=xxxxx"></script>
```

But in order for this to work, the values that /mylist?username=xxxxx returns/generates need to be valid JavaScript.

How can I get my view to render to JavaScript?

Comment: you can write a javascript which adds the elements to DOM

Answer (score 1):

You could return a [`JavaScriptResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) from your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Mylist()
{
    return JavaScript("alert('Hello World');");
}
```

or return a view which will contain javascript:

```
public ActionResult Mylist()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    model.Message = "foo bar";
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
    return View(model);
}
```

and then you could have a corresponding view which will contain javascript:

```
@model MyViewModel
alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Message)));
```

Comment: The "html" that I am rendering is somewhat complicated so I cannot just create a string in the action method and I don't want to be escaping each of the special characters. I was hoping I could keep the view as is, use something to render the view as a string, then use something like a JavaScriptSerializer to turn that string into a javascript string and then I could do a document.write() to insert the rendered elements into the DOM of the embedded page.

Comment: Then you could use the second approach I have illustrated. You could JSON serialize your entire model using the `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` function and pass it to some javascript method.

Comment: Am I better off just using an iframe directly or having this javascript just insert the iframe into the DOM?

Comment: No, you are not better off using iframes.